# Django: TypeError : __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I apologize if this is silly. But I’m unable to understand this error message :

This is my forms.py:

```
class group1Form(forms.ModelForm):      
    class Meta:
        model = group1
        fields = ('group_Name', 'Master', 'Nature_of_group1', 'balance_nature', 'Group_behaves_like_a_Sub_Ledger', 'Nett_Debit_or_Credit_Balances_for_Reporting')
        widgets = {
            'group_Name': forms.TextInput(attrs= {'class' : 'form-control'}),

        }

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(group1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['Master'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control select2',}
            self.fields['Nature_of_group1'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control select2',}
            self.fields['balance_nature'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control select2',}
```

This is my views.py:

```
class group1CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class  = group1Form
    template_name = "accounting_double_entry/group1_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.User = self.request.user
        form.instance.Company = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super(group1CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Error Tracrbacks:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

  File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    Exception Type: TypeError at /accounting_double_entry/groupcreate/
    Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly I am doing wrong in this code???
Just cant figure it out

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the error traceback?

Comment: I have edited my code@JPG

Comment: If the indentation is correct, you wrote the `__init__` *in* the `Meta` class, not in the `group1Form`.

Comment: Did you perhaps wrote in the `urls.py` just `group1CreateView` instead of `group1CreateView.as_view()`?

Comment: Can you share the relevant `urls.py`?

Comment: Itz solved...You was right I have written group1CreateView instead of group1CreateView.as_view()...Thank you@WillemVanOnsem